# How to add to existing StyleSheet in ReactNative. How to use spread operator with StyleSheet?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Referencing the StyleSheet defined style directly works. However, using the spread operator on the StyleSheet defined style completely ignores the styles defined in the StyleSheet.

As shown in the below code example

Does not work:

```
{...MyCommonStyles.outerExampleView, alignItems:'flex-end'}
```

While the exact reference works:

```
 <View style={MyCommonStyles.outerExampleView}>
```

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

interface StyleIssueScreenProps {
}

export const MyCommonStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    outerExampleView: {
        borderColor: 'orange',
        borderWidth: 3
    }
});

export class StyleIssueScreen extends React.Component<StyleIssueScreenProps> {
    render() {
        return <View>
            <View style={MyCommonStyles.outerExampleView}>
                <Text>{'Works with exact ref'}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{...MyCommonStyles.outerExampleView, alignItems:'flex-end'}}>
                <Text>{'Does not work with span expansion'}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    }
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
        <StyleIssueScreen/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

[image]

Code: https://snack.expo.io/1u9R_ZkTa

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to apply multiple styles to a single component, the style prop will take an array. In your case it would look like:

```
<View style={[ MyCommonStyles.outerExampleView, {alignItems: 'flex-end'} ]}>
  <Text>{'Does not work with span expansion'}</Text>
</View>
```

Is this the outcome you are after?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen two ways to do this.

One is creating the StyleSheet object and using the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to create a new Style. E.g.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outerExampleView: {
    ...MyCommonStyles.outerExampleView,
    alignItems: "flex-end"
  }
});
```

The second way is to do it in-line, but note you will receive a minor performance hit as you will be re-creating the Style every time render() is called.

```
<View style={StyleSheet.flatten([MyCommonStyles.outerExampleView, {alignItems:'flex-end'}])>
  <Text>{'Does not work with span expansion'}</Text>
</View>
```

I would only use the second method when the provided value is dynamic. E.g. From an API or computed.

Comment: I would think the first makes alot of sense. However, when trying it out the style do not take hold example snack using the first way: https://snack.expo.io/22rIbcvLW